# Get data from html node in vbnet

Tags: .net, html, vb.net

I have a basic anchor node as a string and would like to get the URL and the text from it.  For example:

```
<a href="http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/">Go to MyAwesomeWebsite</a>
```

I want two strings, one with:

```
http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/
```

and the other with

```
MyAwesomeWebsite
```

How do I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expressions to extract the text that you want as next:

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
    Sub Main()
    Dim anchor As String
    anchor = "<a href=""http://MyAwesomeWebsite.com/"">Go to MyAwesomeWebsite</a>"

    Dim href As String = Regex.Match(anchor, "\""[a-z,A-Z,0-9,:,/,.]+\""").Value
    Console.WriteLine(href.Substring(1, href.Length - 2))

    Dim content As String = Regex.Match(anchor, "\>[a-z,A-Z,0-9,:,/,., ]+\<").Value
    Console.WriteLine(content.Substring(1, content.Length - 2))
    Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
```

Also you can use the methods provided by **String** like **IndexOf** and **Substring**.
But if you are thinking on parse a lot of those thinks I suggest you use a library like [HtmlAgilePack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks!  But sometimes is the link contains a 'rel' attribute that will come up as the hyper reference.  Any easy fix in regex?  Or should I use the library.  I'm trying to avoid using a library for just one small task.

Comment: If your target is examine the 'rel' page is better use the library.But If you just want to get the value of 'rel' you can use another regular expression as next: `Dim rel As String = Regex.Match(anchor, "rel=\""[a-z,A-Z,0-9,:,/,.]+\""").Value
    Console.WriteLine(rel.Substring(5, rel.Length - 6))
` If you want check if the regex has matched before use it (to difference between use regex for 'href' or 'rel'), you can use **Regex.IsMatch**. I hope help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library can parse string for you and return any information you want. Here is [plenty of related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Html+Agility+Pack) on stackoverflow on how to use it.

Another method involves using [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to find substrings that matches required pattern.